# Как передать в метод ссылку на переменную

Tags: java

При передачи в метод переменной через аргументы, передается ее значение, то есть создается новый ее экземпляр. Изменение этого экземпляра никак не влияет на переменную, которую передали.

Можно ли передать именно ссылку на переменную (чтобы изменение переменной, поступившей через аргументы, влекло за собой изменение переменной, переданной через аргументы) и, если да, то как?

---

Пример:

```
class Main {
    int a = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        myMethod(a);
    }

    void myMethod(int b) {
        b++;
    }
}
```

Как передать `a` так, чтобы изменение `b` повело за собой изменение `a`.

Comment: что за переменная? -_- пример

Comment: @Suvitruf, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Правильный ответ: никак.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оберните ее во что-нибудь, Например:

```
public class Container {
    public int myVar;
}
```

передаете этот контейнер, `function(Container c)` и меняете там значение спокойно.

Но вообще это плохая практика. Все должно быть иммутабельно.

Гораздо лучше если вы делаете так:

```
public int myFunction(int arg) {
    int result = ...     //совершаем действия с arg
    return result;
}
```

Comment: А более простых способов нет?(

Comment: покажите свой код, более простой способ - написать правильно.

Comment: Тут не в коде дело... Видимо, нет больше способов...

Comment: Через 4 минуты приму ответ (сайт ругается).

Comment: @bukashka101 старайтесь держать функции чистыми (без сайд эффектов). Сэкономите себе кучу времени потом в отладке и тестировании.

Comment: Что такое "сайд эффекты"?

Comment: В вашем случае - изменение состояния. Т.е. вызвав ваш метод два раза с одним и тем же аргументом вы получите разные значения. А вообще [вот](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Answer (score 2):

Можно, к примеру, использовать универсальный дженерик.

```
class Main {
    Reference<Integer> a = new Reference<>(0);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        myMethod(a);
    }


   void myMethod(Reference<Integer> ref){
       ref.set(ref.get() + 1);
   }
}



public class Reference<T> {
    private T referent;

    public Reference(T initialValue) {
       referent = initialValue;
    }

    public void set(T newVal) {
       referent = newVal;
    }

    public T get() {
       return referent;
    }
}
```

Comment: @DmitryV. не абстрактный

Answer (score 2):

Фактически @Dmitry V. уже писал об этом - не хочу забирать чужую славу и сделал ответ общим. Хотелось бы немного расширить.

В *Java* нет такого действия, как передача аргумента по ссылке, от него решили отказаться в пользу прозрачности действий и избежания неочевидных ошибок. Таким образом есть простое правило:

> В *Java* все аргументы передаются по значению

Что делать в ситуации, аналогичной ситуации в вопросе, когда требуется из метода влиять на глобальные переменные.
Сразу обратим внимание, что оборачивание в контейнеры и дженерики хоть и решают задачу, но реализиют ее излишне сложно и не очевидно при чтении кода третьими лицами, без явной необходимости именно в таком решении от него следует отказаться.

Между тем есть простой  "канонический" способ этого действия - возврат значения методом:

```
class Main {
    int a = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        a = myMethod(a);
    }

    int myMethod(int b) {
     return b++;
    }
}
```

Кроме того, если в душе вы индус, то можно вообще положить на каноны и условности и работать в методе напрямую с глобальной переменной:

```
class Main {
    int a = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        myMethod();
    }

    void myMethod() {
        a++;
    }
}
```

помимо попертых "общекультурных" ценностей языка мы так же видим и очевидные недостатки - метод не универсален и работает только с одной глобальной переменной, но таково быть индусом.
Однако стоит заметить, что данный сарказм будет не уместен при использовании глобальной переменной по ее прямому назначению - доступность во всех методах класса. При таком использовании значение глобальной переменной вполне можно менять в методах напрямую, особенно если ее изменение - не цель работы метода и возвращать метод должен другое значение (код в данном вопросе не относится к такому типу использования, поэтому предпочтителен первый вариант).

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт о типе int, то передавай вместо примитива int через обёртку Integer. Все примитивные типы в Java передаётся по значению, а все объекты по ссылке. Вот и всё)

Comment: Нет, это не правильно. В методе будет создана локальная копия глобальной переменной с областью видимости в пределах метода.

Comment: Вы говорите о примитиве?

Comment: Если да, то я согласен, примитивы передаются по значению и создаётся их копия с областью видимости метода.

Comment: Любые переданные аргументы. Примитивы и объекты .

Comment: Секунду, проверю, мне кажется, вы ошибаетесь.

Comment: http://www.quizful.net/interview/java/passing-parameters-reference-value
"В Java объекты всегда передаются по ссылке, а примитивы - по значению
Pass By Reference means the passing the address itself rather than passing the value. Pass By Value means passing a copy of the value to be passed."

Comment: Я сейчас начал гуглить и затестил, и понял, что не прав. Но тогда я не понимаю, почему в статье говорится так?

Comment: Это объясняется в любом учебнике по Java. Передается ссылка и по ней создается локальная копия. Сделано для избежания недоразумений - в Java все аргументы передаются по значению, легко запомнить, трудно сделать ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Я все переменные значение которых используется в разных методах делаю глобальными для класса.
Если объекты/переменные используются в разных классах, то делаю отдельный класс для переменных и другие классы работают с объектом этого класса-хранилища переменных.
Просто при объявлении какого-то нового класса передаю ему ссылку на объект хранилища и все. Зато не нужно дублировать по 10 раз, если много общих переменных.